# Magento invoice printing error after a custom theme installed

Tags: error, blocks, invoice, print, head

My problem is printing invoice issue,I noticed that this started since i installed a new theme, i installed a theme (from EMThemes website) and whenever i try to print a sales invoice from the customer dashboard or during after checkout, i get an error titled as follows:

**`"There has been an error processing your request"`**

and followed by the follow error codes:

```
Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addEMItem(Array
(
    [0] => skin_css
    [1] => css/em_variation.css
    [2] => Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element Object
        (
        )

    [3] => general_disable_frontend_variation
    [4] => 1
)
)

Trace:
#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('addEMItem', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head->addEMItem('skin_css', 'css/em_variatio...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), 'general_disable...', '1')
#2 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Controller/Abstract.php(181): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout('print')
#9 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract->printAction()
#10 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print')
#11 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /homepages/45/d633723370/htdocs/reficcocontrol/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Please I need help rectifying this error,am very new to magento,a detailed instruction would be appreciated,am on magento 1.8.1,thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your custom theme, search the xml file which include "em_variation.css" in head.

There are many method to include css in header. So change it according to this.

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addCss">
       <stylesheet>path/to_your/em_variation.css</stylesheet>
   </action>
</reference>
```

Or you can used this one as well.

You can try this code as well.

```
<head>
    <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/styles.css"/>
</head>
```

Comment: I tried that but nothing seems to work. Then I did this: I opened my page.xml file,replaced all instances of "addEMItem" with "addItem", then i comment out "addEMResposiveRtlCss"....after doing these, i discovered i could now print invoices..it was a good news,but the problem now is..my website pages are all messed up,seems no css and js are loaded up anymore..please help,i don't mind giving out my ftp to any developer willing to help,thanks

Comment: I am edit my answer, it can help you.